# How to show jquery form validation plugin errors below the form fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am using [jQuery form validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to verify the form.. It is working perfectly.. But problem is that it is showing error message next to form field in the same row.. I want to show this error message below the text field like [first form in this example](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/). I don't want to redefine error messages in validate function. What is the shortest way.

I am applying plugin like this:

```
$(".ValidateForm").validate();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer. I restricted the width of the `<td></td>` in which form element is rendered and error message is shown below the form fields because of low space.